# C# public variables problem

Tags: c#

This is a noob question

```
using System.name;

class class_name
{
    private className Obj;

    public class_name()
    {
    }

    public function()
    {
       Obj.function     <----- why i cant acesss the global varible here ??
    }
}
```

When i type the class the instellisence docent show any thing :-s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming there was just some confusion with the names and, by `function`, you meant `class_name`, or instead of `class_name` you meant `className`.

In order to access a method this way, it must be declared as static. Otherwise, you must first create an instance of the class and access the method through the instance.

**EDIT** The code you posted is very confusing. The following works just fine for me.

```
class Class1
{
    public void Function1()
    {
    }
}

class Class2
{
    private Class1 obj;

    public void Function2()
    {
        obj.Function1();
    }
}
```

Comment: i already created  a global `private className Obj;` but cannot acesss from the `function` because its not static ?

Comment: No, you've created a class member. And, again, if you don't declare the member as static, then you must create an instance of the class in order to access that member. If you want to access it this way, declare it as `private static className obj;`.

Comment: Fix your symbol names. It's very confusing. I think you've not used the same name for references to the same symbol.

Comment: `private classsName Obj = new Classname();`  but same prob !

Comment: Where is `className` declared? If you want help, can't you just take a minute and fix your errors?

Comment: `className` is a class from a imported namespace .. sorry for confusing !

Comment: @Sudantha: See my updated answer. Your code is unclear so it's hard to tell what you are trying to do or why it doesn't work.

Comment: thanks !! i think its sme thing wrong with the inteelisence :-S

Comment: Intellisense is sometimes slow to come around. Or there may be an issue with the library reference or namespace. One more thing: In my code, `obj` is *not* a global variable. It is a member variable.

Answer (score 1):

Have you instantiated that class?

Comment: yep ! `private className Obj;`

Comment: @Sudantha Try private className obj = new className();